# Change Double Number displaying format?

Tags: c#, format, double, display

In C#, if a double number has more than 5 zero (ex: 0.0000456), it will display as 4.56E-05. But I want to display as 0.0000456. Is there anyway to change the display format? Please help!

Comment: Have you looked through the numeric format strings page on MSDN?

Comment: See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use formatting to accomplish this.**

```
        double test = 0.0000456;

        Console.WriteLine(test);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:F7}", test);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

```
        4.56E-05
        0.0000456
```

**Max**

```
        double test = 
        0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        0000000000000000000000000000000001;

        Console.WriteLine(test);

        Console.WriteLine("{0:F99}", test);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

```
1E-99
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000001;
```

Comment: Ok F99 seems ok. Thanks both of you , ReRoute and Solver.